# When I'm trying to install a free app on my iPhone, it'll say:

Tags: iphone

When I'm trying to install a free app on my iPhone, it'll say:

> "Verification Required
>
> Before you can make purchases, you must tap continue to verify your
>   payment info."

Why do I see then when it's free?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: There are many sites where this kind of question is appropriate (Apple forums, Apple support, etc.). This site is not one of them. You've been here long enough you should know better.

Comment: Iam sorry for posting this question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily download free application with out payment option. try following steps.

1. Open App store or iTune Store.
2. Search any free application , song or video
3. Tap free next to the item and tap again
4. Once pop up wind opens hit "CREATE A NEW ACCOUNT"
5. Make sure you use a fresh email that you haven't attempted to use for creating account
6. Fill all required details and once you reach at payment information screen then you can found a option of 'NONE' So select it.
7. Fill your billing information
8. Enjoy a free application.......:)

Comment: this is a good steps for figure out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your payment info such as your credit card number, your first and last name, date of birth and billing address even if you want to install free apps only.

You can do it in itunes app on your mac by clicking "iTunes store" button on the top left corner and then clicking on button with your apple on the top right corner. Or you can do it with your iOS device.